# https redirection in php website hosting on godaddy server

Tags: php

I have created one website using php and hosting on godaddy server in this server i have use ssl certificate for security purpose and using web.config file i have write some code of redirection http to https
Below my code is:-

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" executionTimeout="3600"  targetFramework="4.5" />
       <customErrors mode="Off"/>
        <trust level="Full"/>
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
         <rules>
             <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
             <match url="(.*)" />
             <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
             </conditions>
             <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
     </rule>
         </rules>
     </rewrite>
      </system.webServer>
      <connectionStrings>
        <add name="mycon" connectionString="Data Source=182.50.133.111;Initial Catalog=TripBrip;Integrated Security=False;User Id=TripBrip;Password=TripBripWork@12;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
      </connectionStrings>
    </configuration>
```

So problem is that this code not properly working when i enter only website link like (asdadminbnm.tripbrip.com) that time https not show but when i enter (https://asdadminbnm.tripbrip.com) that time secure https show. My code automatically not redirected to https code so which way i solve this problem any one please help me